# Where does Chrome store video clips watched but then erased when turned off?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, video

Chrome store video clips you have watched somewhere on the computer and then erases them when you turn it off or maybe even when you leave the url.? Where is that in windows 10? In XP it was about 10 layers deep in applications. I haven't gotten proficient enough to even look for em.

Answer (score 3):

On my computer it is currently `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\Cache`
You will need to enable `Show hidden files, folders, and drives` in `Folder Options` to see `AppData`.

FYI, I *believe* Google has changed the location somewhat in the past (I don't remember there being a `Profile 1` folder), so this may not always be accurate.

I use **VideoCacheView** from NirSoft to easily find where videos are stored; works great. It will show you all cached videos and allow you to copy or view them.
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/video_cache_view.html

Comment: While I can see why you'd make an assumption and suggest this, it doesn't answer the question being asked.

Comment: True...edited to clarify. Better?

Comment: "Default" is the default profile folder